# jQuery POST not working on some browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am writing a code where a user can fill a form and the form details will be sent via $.post

Here is the code:

```
$.post("save.php",{userName:userName,message:message},function(data,status){alert('Thank you');});
```

The code is working perfectly on my laptop but many of my users are saying that it's not working on their laptop/mobile device.

Is there anything i can do to enable compatibility of $.post on all browsers?

I have included jquery from here:
    https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: better to ask your users what kind of errors they are experiencing and start from there.

Comment: When working on your computer are you on localhost? If so consider impending the full URL instead of just "save.php"

Comment: i am not on localhost. i am deploying the files to the server and then testing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use jquery 1.11.xx because 2 version is not work for many browser and devices.

for example the official browser support info:

```
Internet Explorer  +9
Chrome   (Current - 1) or Current
Firefox  (Current - 1) or Current
Safari  5.1+
Opera  12.1x, (Current - 1) or Current
iOS   6.1+
Android  4.0+
```

Downgrade the jquery.

Comment: i have downgraded the jquery. waiting for my users to test it for a few days and see if they face any error. thanks for the info :)

Comment: thanks Mahdi. none of my users have complained. i think the script is working fine now :)